# Can I control how Oracle maps the integer types in ADO.NET?

Tags: oracle, ado.net

I've got a legacy database that was created with the database type INTEGER for many (1.000+) Oracle columns. A database with the same structure exists for MS SQL. As I was told, the original definition was created using a tool that generated the scripts from a logical model to the specific one for MS SQL and Oracle.

Using C++ and MFC the columns were mapped nicely to the integer type for both DBMs.

I am porting this application to .NET and C#. The same C# codebase is used to access both MS SQL and Oracle. We use the same DataSets and logic and we need the same types (int32 for both).

The ODP.NET driver from Oracle maps them to Decimal. This is logical as Oracle created the integer columns as NUMBER(37) automatically. The columns in MS SQL map to int32.

Can I somehow control how to map the types in the ODP.NET driver? I would like to say something like "map NUMBER(37) to int32". The columns will never hold values bigger than the limits of an int32. We know this because it is being used in the MS SQL version.

Alternatively, can I modify all columns from NUMBER(37) to NUMBER(8) or SIMPLE_INTEGER so that they map to the right type for us? Many of these columns are used as primary keys (think autoincrement).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding type mapping, hope this is what you need
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/entityDataTypeMapping.htm#ODPNT8300
Regarding type change, if table is empty, you may use following script (just replace [YOUR_TABLE_NAME] with table name in upper case):

```
DECLARE
  v_table_name CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30) := '[YOUR_TABLE_NAME]';
BEGIN
  FOR col IN (SELECT * FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = v_table_name AND data_type = 'NUMBER' AND data_length = 37)
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||v_table_name||' MODIFY '||col.column_name||' NUMBER(8)';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

If some of these columns are not empty, then you can't decrease precision for them
If you have not too much data, you may move it to temp table

```
create table temp_table as select * from [YOUR_TABLE_NAME]
```

then truncate original table

```
truncate [YOUR_TABLE_NAME]
```

then run script above
then move data back

```
insert /*+ append */ into [YOUR_TABLE_NAME] select * from temp_table
commit
```

If data amount is substantial it is better to move it once. In such case it is faster to create new table with correct datatypes and all indexes, constraints and so on, then move data, then rename both tables to make new table have proper name.

Comment: Thank you Anton. The first link will not work for us as this is for the Entity Framework and we need something for ADO.NET. I think a mate already checked it and it does not work with ADO.NET. I will ask him again or check it myself and give you feedback.

Comment: As for the second part: There are more than 400 tables in the database(s) and more than 1.000 fields need to be modified. The database are not empty (some of them are 100+ GB big). There are MANY indexes and foreign keys between the tables and the columns to modify are usually part of them. As I said they are used as primery keys.

Comment: My mate tells me that he tried your first solution some months ago. The config entry is just for telling which data types to use as default when creating the models. We need something for ADO.NET that can do the mapping when running addhoc queries. The Oracle driver from a company called DevArt can do this, but sadly we are not allowed to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the mapping of numeric types between .NET and Oracle is hardcoded in OracleDataReader class.

1. In general I usually prefer to setup appropriate data types in the database, so if possible I would change the column datatypes because they better represent the actual values and their constraints.
2. Another option is to wrap the tables using views casting to NUMBER(8) but will negatively impact execution plans because it prohibits index lookups.

Then you have also some application implementation options:

1. Implement your own data reader or subset of ADO.NET classes (inheriting from DbProviderFactory, DbConnection, DbCommmand, DbDataReader, etc. and wrapping Oracle classes), depending on how complex is your implementation. Oracle.DataAccess, Devart and all providers do exactly the same because it gives total control over everything including any magic with the data types. If the datatype conversion is the only thing you want to achieve, most of the implementation would be just calling wrapped class methods/properties.
2. If you have access to OracleDataReader after command is executed and before you start to read it you can do a simple hack and set the resulting numeric type using reflection (following implementation is just simplified demonstration).

However this will not work with ExecuteScalar as this method never exposes the underlying data reader.

```
var connection = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=HQ_PDB_TCP;PASSWORD=oracle;USER ID=HUSQVIK");
connection.Open();

var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL";

var reader = command.ExecuteDatabaseReader();
reader.Read();
Console.WriteLine(reader[0].GetType().FullName);
Console.WriteLine(reader.GetFieldType(0).FullName);

public static class DataReaderExtensions
{
    private static readonly FieldInfo NumericAccessorField = typeof(OracleDataReader).GetField("m_dotNetNumericAccessor", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    private static readonly object Int32DotNetNumericAccessor = Enum.Parse(typeof(OracleDataReader).Assembly.GetType("Oracle.DataAccess.Client.DotNetNumericAccessor"), "GetInt32");
    private static readonly FieldInfo MetadataField = typeof(OracleDataReader).GetField("m_metaData", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    private static readonly FieldInfo FieldTypesField = typeof(OracleDataReader).Assembly.GetType("Oracle.DataAccess.Client.MetaData").GetField("m_fieldTypes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    public static OracleDataReader ExecuteDatabaseReader(this OracleCommand command)
    {
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var columnNumericAccessors = (IList)NumericAccessorField.GetValue(reader);
        columnNumericAccessors[0] = Int32DotNetNumericAccessor;

        var metadata = MetadataField.GetValue(reader);
        var fieldTypes = (Type[])FieldTypesField.GetValue(metadata);
        fieldTypes[0] = typeof(Int32);

        return reader;
    }
}
```

I implemented extension method for command execution returning the reader where I can set up the desired column numeric types. Without setting the numeric accessor (it's just internal enum Oracle.DataAccess.Client.DotNetNumericAccessor) you will get System.Decimal, with accessor set you get Int32. Using this you can get all Int16, Int32, Int64, Float or Double.
columnNumericAccessors index is a column index and it will applied only to numeric types, if column is DATE or VARCHAR the numeric accessor is just ignored. If your implementation doesn't expose the provider specific type, make the extension method on IDbCommand or DbCommand and then safe cast the DbDataReader to OracleDataReader.

EDIT: Added the hack for GetFieldType method. But it might happen that the static mapping hashtable might be updated so this could have unwanted effects. You need to test it properly. The fieldTypes array holds the types returned for all columns of the data reader.

Comment: Thank you Husqvik. This goes in the right direction. We used reflection and saw that we just need to override one method! Sadly, the method cannot be overriden. We could use Cecil from the Mono project to modify the accessor for the method but I don't think that Oracle would like that :-) If nobody has a better answer you will get the bounty for the question. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: Which method do you want to override?

Comment: I was wrong. The method itself (OracleDataReader.GetFieldType) is public. Our problem was that it is not enough to create a derived class and override de method. You must override all classes that are creating OracleDataReaders as well. Wouldn't it be nice if they used dependency injection for it? :-)

Comment: As it seems yours is the best answer, We didn't yet try it, but at least looks like a possible way. You deserve the bounty.Thank you.

Comment: I get a message telling me that I can set the bounty in two hours.

Comment: I am sorry this will not work as well. I cannot do any inheriting  from the classes because they are sealed. Strange thing to declare the methods as override when you seal the classes.

Comment: I'm not overriding anything. Just modifying internal members of OracleDataReader. It's implementation is sealed, that's true, so if you want to override it you can't do it directly but inheriting the base class - DbDataReader. That's why I described two ways. The first is proper, the second is just hack. The methods are overridden because they override the DbDataReader methods too, OracleDataReader is inherited from DbDataReader.

Comment: To anyone that could be interested: this approach will not work. The class OracleDataReader is sealed and uses lots of internal classes as well. There is no way to override the needed methods. @Husqvik: even when you answer was not the solution, you get the bounty for pointing to the right answer: you cannot override the mapping as today.

Comment: Uppps! Sorry. I didn't read your last comment. My browser didn't update the content.